# How to mock nodes for AG-grid in unit test for Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is there any way to mock nodes of AG-grid in unit test?
Component doesn't have agInit.

And I don't see any way to mock it yet.
I need to execute forEachNode and check "if" branches inside it

Answer (score 2):

this is an example how we are currently mocking ag-grid functions with Angular :

```
let gridApiMock: GridApi;

      beforeEach(async () => {
    gridApiMock = Mock.of<GridApi>({
      deselectAll: () => [],
      setRowData: () => [],
      paginationGetCurrentPage: () => 0,
      getSelectedNodes: () => [
        {
          data: {
            id: '6149fa57f119aa206c420f44',
...
       
          }
        }
      ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i was able to mock the implementation and test the logic inside for each node

```
 const mockGridApi = new GridApi();
    const nodes = [{  
    data: {
    id: '6149fa57f119aa206c420f44',
    }
    }]
    jest.spyOn(mockGridApi, 'forEachNode')
    .mockImplementation((forEach: Function) => {
    nodes.forEach((node) => forEach(node));
    });
```